# linking to sports.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, support, editing, closing-questions

Curious why this option isn't enabled when close voting. Currently I can only select "meta.fitness.stackexchange.com" for closing a question that belongs somewhere else, [like this one](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20994/action-group-game-for-adults-teenagers).

This is the second or third scenario like this I've run across. Is the protocol to move it over here, then have someone with geared up mod powers move it somewhere else on the network?

Answer (score 1):

You have the required reputation for it. According to how [migration works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), you should at least see another option to select another site. Even not, you can always flag the question.

That question in particular though wouldn't be a good fit on Sports either. It's too broad.