# can't vote to migrate to a different stackexchange site

Tags: support, migration

[I've had this problem in the past](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/585/linking-to-sports-stackexchange-com), and sat around wondering if it would magically fix itself. There are a few times when I think something would be a great fit on another site. [Like below](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/26075/increased-consumption-of-green-salads-does-it-indicate-deficiency-of-certain-m), which probably would be fine on health.stackexchange.com. Alas, I can't recommend that.

My only migration option is to this meta.

[image]

Comment: Sweet, just got the tumbleweed badge for this incredibly boring and unpopular question.

Comment: Its because we're in beta, have a look at this meta.SE post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258593/do-the-new-graduation-policies-have-any-effect-on-migrations-to-beta-sites